# Magento Custom button add Custom Controller URL

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

I added a button in the Admin under Catalog->Category. Now I would like this button to have the URL or click function that redirects to my custom controller in the admin. But I can't seem to generate the proper URL format. I tested the Custom Controller and the endpoints works. I just need to incorporate it with a button. So whenever I click this button it redirects or calls an ajax to this button `(but redirecting is ok for now)` below is how I created the button

> File location: /app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/ClearCacheButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AbstractCategory;

/**
 * Class ClearCacheButton
 */
class ClearCacheButton extends AbstractCategory implements ButtonProviderInterface
{    
    /**
     * Clear Cache button
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $category = $this->getCategory();
        $categoryId = (int)$category->getId();    
        $url = $this->getUrl('vendormodule/menu/index'); // This does not generate the desired URL for the custom module
        if ($categoryId) {
            return [
                'id' => 'clear_cache',
                'label' => __('Clear Cache Menu'),
                'onclick' => "setLocation(\'" . $url . "\')",          
                'class' => 'save',
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'url' => $url
            ];
        }

        return [];
    }
}
```

Also added the ui_component as shown below

> File location: /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="clear_cache" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\ClearCacheButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</form>
```

Here is the routes.xml

> File location: /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <!--Use router 'admin' for admin route -->
    <router id="admin">
        <!--Define a custom route with id and frontName -->
        <route id="vendormodule" frontName="vendormodule">
            <!--The module which this route match to-->
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Note: Custom controller definition is correct as I have tested it and didn't bother to add it here.

Comment: You don't actually show your controller file in your question. I have a button working from a form to a controller which enacts a redirect, and doesn't require implementing 'ButtonRedirectInterface', but to answer I would need to know where your Controller was in your project path

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code. Hope this will help you.

```
public function getButtonData()
{
    $category = $this->getCategory();
    $categoryId = (int)$category->getId();  
    if ($categoryId) {
        return [
            'id' => 'clear_cache',
            'label' => __('Clear Cache Menu'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getCustomUrl()),       
            'class' => 'save',
            'sort_order' => 10,
            'url' => $url
        ];
    }

    return [];
}



public function getCustomUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('frontname/yourControllerName/Action');
}
```

Comment: This is almost the same with my approach it's just that you use sprintf instead of setlocation. I was thinking of different approach if possible.